# Check Variables and Statements dependency in Loop of a java Class

Tags: java, multithreading

suppose i have a java method (array addition for example)

```
public void mymethod() {   
  { 
   //i have some global arrays named a, b & c
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     a[i]=b[i]+c[i];     //no dependency exists
  }
```

here if i convert this loop into 2 separate loops and run using two threads. the result would be accurate. but in a case like given below

```
public void mymethod() {   
  { 
   //i have some global arrays named a, b
  for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
     a[i]=b[i]+a[i-1];           //a[i] dependent on a[i-1]
  }
```

the next value of a[i] depends upon previous value of a[i-1]. so there exists a dependency in the loop and it can't be parallelized just by dividing the loop into two separate loops.

so my question;

**Is there any JAVA class/tool/package etc to check such type of dependency in a loop**?

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) or find any other java code analysys tools.

Comment: as per my information , JDepend is a class dependency finder. not a loop dependency finder.